# Devise Redirect After Cancellation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, devise

I want to redirect customers to a survey after they cancel their subscription, but having a difficult time getting the session destroyed along with the redirecting to the survey.

organizations_controller.rb:

```
def cancel
    if @organization.subscription.cancel
      redirect_to "http://example.com/contact/cancel?organization=#{@organization.resource_id}"
    else
      flash[:error] = "An error has occurred."
      redirect_to settings_profile_path
    end
  end
```

How can I utilize the devise `destroy_user_session_path` and redirect to the suvery at the same time without overriding the redirect path of a normal user signing out. I just need this to work when an organization cancels.

Comment: um, you could manually unset the sessions or call logout_user ?

Comment: @argentum47 `destroy_user_session_path` above the `redirect_to` doesn't seem to work... it redirects to the survey; however, the user is still signed in. If I say `redirect_to destroy_user_session_path && "http://example.com/contact/cancel?organization=#{@organization.resource_id}"`, it logs the user out, but doesn't redirect. It's like saying you can have one, but not the other.

Comment: u passing the object inside destroy_user_session_path(@user) right? atleast try sign_out(@user) then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `destroy_user_session_path` with `sign_out_all_scopes(lock=true)` (a devise helper) did the trick.

```
def cancel
    if @organization.subscription.cancel
      sign_out_all_scopes(lock=true)
      redirect_to "http://example.com/contact/cancel?organization=#{@organization.resource_id}"
    else
      flash[:error] = "An error has occurred."
      redirect_to settings_profile_path
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the question. Do you want to destroy the session thus logging out the user? If so, try this: In your application controller add this private method

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(user)
  if blah
    redirect_to :foo
  else
    redirect_to :bar        
  end
end
```